Visa to China for Irish passport holder
I am planning a trip to China this autumn. I have booked the following flights:
Shanghai: October 30th - November 5th (7 days).
Beijing: November 30th - December 12th (13 days).
I am an Irish passport holder. According to the Chinese embassy , “citizens holding Ireland, Switzerland, Hungary, Austria, Belgium, Luxembourg ordinary passports traveling to China for business, tourism, family visit or transit purposes with the duration not exceeding 15 days, are eligible for visa-free entry.”
Am I correct in thinking that I will not need a visa because both trips are under 15 days? Or is it different because I am making two trips?

The FAQ on the offical embassy website states pretty clearly that multiple entries are allowed as long as you don't abuse the system:

Question 10: Are multiple entries allowed？Are there requirements for duration of entry intervals? Are there limits on the number of visa-free entries or total days of stay limit?
Answer: Foreign citizens eligible for visa-free entry to China can enter multiple times. Currently, there are no restrictions on the number of visa-free entries or total days of stay limit. It is of vital importance to keep in mind not to be engaged in activities inconsistent with your purpose of entry.


Ahh I could not find that. Thanks so much!
